# Unhiding row on cell change

Tags: variables, excel, object, vba

This is a slight duplication in question, but I believe it may simplify the situation.

Object of code: When a user picks an entry from the cell validation (i.e. on change) code must

- enter user name in H column
- enter time stamp in I column
- Unhide next row
- (Unexpected next step, show lines that aren't user interactive)

Steps 1 to 3 are now functional, step 4 is not

Current code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ChangedCell As Object


       For Each ChangedCell In Target
            If ChangedCell.Column = 5 And ChangedCell <> "" Then
                Cells(ChangedCell.Row, 8) = Environ("USERNAME")
                Cells(ChangedCell.Row, 9) = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
                ChangedCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                If Cells(ChangedCell.Offset(1, 0), 1).Value <> "HC" Then
                ChangedCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
            End If
       Next
End Sub
```

Rob.

Comment: Try `Cells(ChangedCell.Row + 1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False`.

Comment: minor, but I would declare `ChangedCell` and `UnHideRow` as `Range` instead of `Object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ChangedCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

N.B :Probable Reason why your code caused error: **Obviously you cant write into a read-only value.**

[image]

**APPENDED ANSWER FOR APPENDED QUESTION (STEP 4_"show lines that aren't user interactive")**:

```
Option Explicit
```

''Assuming informative (non interactive) cells are merged and this is upto Column E's last row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ChangedCell As Object
Dim last_Row, iter
last_Row = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.count, 5).End(xlUp).Row      ''change sheet name if different

       For Each ChangedCell In Target
          If ChangedCell.Column = 5 And ChangedCell <> "" Then

                For iter = 1 To last_Row
                ChangedCell.Offset(iter, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                On Error GoTo errhand
                   If ChangedCell.Offset(iter, 0).MergeArea.Address = ChangedCell.Offset(iter, 0).Address Then
                   On Error GoTo 0
                   Cells(ChangedCell.Row, 8) = Environ("USERNAME")
                   Cells(ChangedCell.Row, 9) = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
                   'MsgBox ChangedCell.Row
                   Exit Sub
                   End If
errhand:
                'MsgBox "info row"
                Next
          End If
       Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't realise the UnHideRow was read only? I thought that since I was creating it, I could do what I wanted with it... Regardless, your line there did the job. Much obliged :) Now I just need to go ahead and re-format every sheet in the book. Thank you!

Comment: Its my pleasure also. Good luck.

Comment: Well so far, so good, got the formatting on a few of the sheets done, and it's all working as advertised - though I've possibly painted myself into a corner as it were, there are a few lines in the sheet which are informational rather than being user interactive (i.e. there's no drop box) and I need these lines and then the next user line to both appear, any suggestions? Or is this a "you need to reformat all your sheets entirely" type problem?

I was looking at something like a second IF after your line, checking column A for "HC" and if not there, unhide next line and re-check, else end if?

Comment: you have a new question it seems. But am not getting it. you want to unhide as before, after that if A column for new upward row <> "HC" , then unhide next row also : upto what end? last row?

Comment: This would be so much easier if I could post a screenshot of the sheet I think!

When your suggested code executes, it does indeed unhide the next line. Which is great. Mostly, the next line, is another instruction for the user, which as with the starting line, they can mark as complete/incomplete/not required. However, there are a few lines that are purely instructional - I need those lines (which do NOT have HC in the first column of the row) to be shown, and for the code to then show (and stop) on the NEXT line to have HC in the first column.

I hope that makes more sense?

Comment: Try: `If ChangedCell.Offset(2, -4) <> "HC" Then ChangedCell.Offset(2, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = False` after previously posted line. Dont know if its your requirement. Post screenshot if possible.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, got interrupted by sleeping.
Example image: http://imageshack.com/a/img540/6070/Mozv9z.jpg
So imagine rows 107 onwards are currently hidden, the user is on row 106, he marks it as complete (column E) row 107 appears, he then marks it as complete, row 108 appears, but as row 108 has no box in column E to be modified, the user can't trigger the next step to appear, also 108 and 109 are merged, so code needs to show the next line and then the next (row 110) line till it shows the next line to start with an HC (row 111) and THEN it stops. I hope that makes more sense now.

Comment: My response is delayed also. See the updated answer. But for future, if new question arise, please do open a new question separately and post that link in the old post and also reference post's link should be cited in new post. Good luck.